# Convert UIKit coordinates to SpriteKit coordinates

Tags: ios, uikit, sprite-kit, coordinate-systems

I am trying to convert normal uikit coordinates (top left origin, width and height go right and down) to Sprite Kit coordinates (origin is at center of node, left and down are negative, right and up are positive).

Does anyone know how to do this? Unfortunately I can't work around this to my knowledge because I am using QuartzCore for drawing on a SKNode. Without converting, I am getting really off drawings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the docs, `SKView` has methods for [Converting Between View and Scene Coordinates](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skview#1657599).

Remember the scene is itself an `SKNode`, so if you need to get from scene coordinates to a particular node coordinate system there's also the methods in [Converting to and from the Node’s Coordinate System](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode#1655457).

Comment: Thanks rickster, that was exactly what I needed. I'm kinda new with stackoverflow... Just wondering what I need to do to say 'your answer was the right one, and I appreciate it'? I can't do the arrow up button until I have 15 rep it says.