# Pointing a popup to point to the word tapped in a text view

Tags: ios, iphone, popup, position

I am in a quandary about how to position the popup on the supplied screenshot to point to the word tapped.  The word in the text view is the one that is grey.  I would show some code but I have none that is relevant other than the code that handles the tap.

Here is some code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    if(segue.identifier == "popOverSegue") {
        let destinationViewController: PopoverViewController = segue.destination as! PopoverViewController
        destinationViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
        destinationViewController.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
        destinationViewController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .down
        destinationViewController.tappedWord = tappedWord
        destinationViewController.definitionText = "This is a test description"

        let x = meaningText.frame.minX
        let y = meaningText.frame.minY

        destinationViewController.popupOrigin = CGPoint(x: x + pointOfTap.x,y:  y + pointOfTap.y)
        destinationViewController.popupSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)


        debugPrint(meaningText)
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot on iPhone 6s]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if these are applicable:

If you are using a `UIButton()` for the highlighted text, you could pretty easily get the button's location using something like the following:

```
let buttonLocation = theButton.frame.origin
print("Buttons location is \(buttonLocation)")
```

Alternatively, if you're using a `UIGestureRecognizer` to open the popover, you could use `location(in: UIView)` to get the tap location (which would be somewhere on/near the highlighted text.

That would go something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let tapView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(TheVC.popover(recognizer:)))
    self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapView)
}

@objc func popover(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let tapLocation = recognizer.location(in: self.view)
    print("Tap occurred at location \(tapLocation)")
}
```

Once you have the location of the tap or the UI element that triggers the tap, you could calculate the popover position from there.

Comment: Calculating the position of the word relative to the text view is what I am having a hard time calculating.  I have the point where the user taps the word, and I have the word itself.  I just 1) Cannot seem to reposition the popup without losing it from the screen entirely and 2) cannot get the position of the text view relative to its view controller.

Comment: For #1, Without seeing code to see what you're referencing, I'd make sure you're calculating and setting your `(x, y)` for the popover frame based on the UIViewController's `self.view`, that way is bounded by something consistent. As for #2, the location of specific text inside a UITextView, maybe something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468187/find-cgpoint-location-of-substring-in-textview? Hard to judge what's causing those issues without more details.

Comment: I'm curious what the x, y values of  `meaningText.frame` and `pointOfTap` are if you were to print them around where that debugPrint is.

Comment: meaningText.frame.minX = 67.0
meaningText.frame.minY = 344.0
tappedWord = (172.5, 35.0)