# Convert between UIKit and SpriteKit coordinate systems

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, coordinate-systems

I'm new to iOS programming, and have almost no experience with SpriteKit, so please forgive me if this is a ridiculous question.

I've been trying to make a basic grid with a 2D array, and I would prefer to work with it from top-left being `0, 0`.

After researching the differences in coordinate systems between UIKit and SpriteKit, I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27158803/10811427) about [Converting Between View and Scene Coordinates](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skview/1520328-convert#1657599) but it doesn't seem to change the y value the way I thought it would. I am guessing that I'm not using it right, or maybe this is not what it's meant to do, I don't know.

When I try this:

```
let convertedCoordinates = convert(cellCoordinates, to: grid)
print(cellCoordinates.y, convertedCoordinates.y)
```

it doesn't seem to have any effect on the y value.

I have found that when I change to "`y: -cy`" in the line `let cellCoordinates = CGPoint(x: cx, y: cy)`
Then it does seem to work the way I am hoping for, but I don't know if that's the only solution or if doing this will work as expected under more complicated situations.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

   override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
      var background: SKShapeNode!
      background = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height))
      background.fillColor = SKColor.lightGray
      self.addChild(background)

      let margin = CGFloat(50)
      let width = frame.size.width - margin
      let height = frame.size.height - margin

      let centerX = frame.midX - width / 2
      let centerY = frame.midY - height / 2

      var grid: SKShapeNode!
      grid = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: width, height: height))
      grid.strokeColor = SKColor.clear
      self.addChild(grid)

      let numRows = 2
      let numCols = 3

      let cellWidth = width / CGFloat(numCols)

      for r in 0..<numRows {
         for c in 0..<numCols {

            let cx = centerX + (cellWidth / 2) + (CGFloat(c) * cellWidth)
            let cy = centerY + (cellWidth / 2) + (CGFloat(r) * cellWidth)

            //***
            let cellCoordinates = CGPoint(x: cx, y: cy)
            //***

            let cellNode = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth))

            let convertedCoordinates = convert(cellCoordinates, to: grid)
            print(cellCoordinates.y, convertedCoordinates.y)

            cellNode.strokeColor = SKColor.black
            cellNode.lineWidth = 5
            cellNode.fillColor = SKColor.darkGray
            cellNode.position = convertedCoordinates

            let textNode = SKLabelNode(text: String("\(r),\(c)"))
            textNode.fontName = "Menlo"
            textNode.fontSize = 60
            textNode.verticalAlignmentMode = .center
            textNode.position = convertedCoordinates

            grid.addChild(cellNode)
            grid.addChild(textNode)
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a philosophical answer than an implementation one.  As far as somehow flipping SpriteKit's coordinate system, well, you're going to be fighting it constantly.  Better to just embrace the system as it is.

The essence of your question though is more one of separation of model and view.  When you say

> I would prefer to work with it from top-left being 0, 0

what you mean is that mentally you're thinking of the game as a grid of cells with 0,0 at the top left.  That's perfectly fine and natural.  That's your model of the game.  But what are you writing in the code?

```
let cx = centerX + (cellWidth / 2) + (CGFloat(c) * cellWidth)
let cy = centerY + (cellWidth / 2) + (CGFloat(r) * cellWidth)
let cellCoordinates = CGPoint(x: cx, y: cy)
let convertedCoordinates = convert(cellCoordinates, to: grid)
```

That's your view struggling to get out.  You have the abstract model grid that you're indexing with r,c with 0,0 at the upper left and whose coordinates increase in unit steps down and to the right.  Then there's the view of the model, which might depend on screen resolution, aspect ratio, device orientation, whatever.  If you keep the two mentally separate, you'll usually find that you can isolate the translation between the two systems to a small interface.  In those places you may have to do things like scale the axes or flip one of them, or stretch things in one direction to match aspect ratios.

In a case like this, if you start with your mental model with your preferred 0,0 in the upper left and think about how the game operates, it'll often be in terms of the cells.  OK, that suggests that maybe a 2D array or an array of arrays is natural.  Maybe the cells will eventually become a class in your game.  They'll probably have a node property that stores the SpriteKit node.  You might wind up with something like this:

```swift
struct boardPosition {
  let row: Int
  let col: Int
}

class Cell {
  let pos: boardPosition
  let node: SKNode

  init(pos: boardPosition, in board: Board) {
    self.pos = pos
    node = SKShapeNode(...)
    board.node.addChild(node)
  }
}

class Board {
  let cells: [[Cell]]
  let node: SKNode

  init(numRows: Int, numColumns: Int) {
    ...
  }

  func movePiece(from: boardPosition, to: boardPosition) {
    let piece = cell[from.row][from.col].removePiece()
    cell[to.row][to.col].addPiece(piece)
  }
}
```

The operation of the game will be in terms of your mental model.  The fact that the y-coordinates of the cells' `SKNode` nodes happen to decrease as the row index increases will be completely buried.

Comment: This is a good point that I hadn't begun to consider, don't expect that it would be better to constantly rearrange the coordinate system, just work with it the way it is. But can you tell me, is the `convert( to:)` function supposed to help with a situation like this, or is it for something else? And could you give me a basic example of a translation interface like you mentioned?

Comment: The convert methods aren't intended for this.  In SpriteKit, you typically have a tree of nodes, and coordinates are relative (e.g., if a child node has position 10,15 in its parent, then that point 10,15 in the parent corresponds to 0,0 in the child).  If you need to switch between coordinate systems (though this is rarely needed), that's what the convert methods are for.

Comment: Regarding an example, you mostly wrote one already mixed in with your code.  The only thing I'd suggest is that you've mixed up `frame` with `grid` a bit.  Frame is referring to the overall scene, and you're deriving centerX and centerY from that. But then you're using those to calculate coordinates of nodes that get added as children of `grid`, which has its own separate coordinate system. Think about the natural coordinates for grid (whether 0,0 will be in the center or a corner is up to you). Compute cell coordinates in grid's space.  Then position `grid` overall in your scene.

Answer (score 0):

Set all nodes applicable and scene’s anchor point to 0,1 to get it to mount to the top left corner and set your world node’s (if you do not have one, I recommend adding it, it is a basic SKNode that you use to place all of your game nodes in, allowing you to use a separate node for things not applicable to the game world, like hud and overlays) yScale to -1 to have y increment downward instead of upward.

Edit:

When dealing with SKShapeNodes, you do not have to worry about the images being inversed unless you have an obscure shape.  When designing the CGPath for the obscure shape, just flip it.

```
shape.path = shape.path!.copy(using:CGAffineTransform(scaleX:1,y:-1))
```

The bigger problem is SKShapeNode does not have anchor points.  You instead need to move the entire CGPath

To do this, add the following line:

```
shape.path = shape.path!.copy(using:CGAffineTransform(translationX:shape.frame.width/2,y:shape.frame.height/2))
```

If dealing with SKSprite nodes in the future....
This will cause your assets to be upside down, so all you would need to do is have your assets flipped before import,  use a secondary node to flip the y axis, or assign all nodes with a yScale of -1.  Flipping all of your assets prior to import vertically would be the cheapest method,  I believe you can flip it inside xcassets as well, but I need to verify that when I get back on a MacOS again.

Comment: I've seen this suggested, but doesn't it wind up with the artwork in child nodes being upside-down?  (I.e., you have to go around yScaling them by -1 to cancel the effect.)  That's why I view this as just fighting against nature.

Comment: Yeah, just slap a second node in to undo it.  Thanks for the comment

Comment: I hadn't done anything in the GameScene.sks yet, so far everything I have is created by the code I posted. I just now set the scene anchor point and I can see that it's now top left. But I don't know how to change the anchor point or scale of the SKShapeNodes as you suggested. I also tried adding a shape node in the Scene editor, but even then I don't see any way to set its anchor or scale.

Comment: SKShapeNodes work based on the CGPath you provide,  little more complex.  I take it you are using the basic shapes based on your code, so you do not need to worry about y flipping in this regard, but your anchor point is impossible.  You would need to wrap it in an SKNode, or move the CGPath since the inits it comes with does not allow to change the origin.

Comment: I provided the code for how to do this with SKShapeNodes now

Comment: Yes, I've simply been using the shapes from code. Trying to convert my learning attempts in Processing "sketches" that I've been working on into the iOS realm as a way to learn iOS programming. It's a lot more complicated than I thought, but maybe as @bg2b has pointed out, it might be better to not try to force one style onto the other.

Comment: Depends on the need, sometimes it is better to stick to the same coordinate system